# Building rowboat-android on BeagleBone Black

Tags: android, embedded, beagleboard

I'm venturing into the land of Android embedded development, and got myself a [BeagleBone Black](http://beagleboard.org/products/beaglebone%20black). I am following [Andrew Henderson's guide](http://icculus.org/~hendersa/android/), and got stuck. I made it to the [kernel portion](http://www.eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-LinuxKernel), and installed the [CA certificates](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/cacerts.html), but when I run the `build_kernel.sh` script, I get

```
+ Detected build host []
+ host: [x86_64]
+ git HEAD commit: [3b8714a41677a022608ba1f4838c94c8c172e496]
Installing: gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf
-----------------------------
--2013-11-13 14:54:12--  https://launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries/trunk/2013.04/+download/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.04-20130415_linux.tar.xz
Resolving launchpad.net... 91.189.89.222, 91.189.89.223
Connecting to launchpad.net|91.189.89.222|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify launchpad.net's certificate, issued by `/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=07969287':
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
To connect to launchpad.net insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.

[Process completed]
```

I've tried running as root, as well as regular user, with the same results. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:

I ran using the --no-check-certificate flag, as the output recommends, and got

```
sh-3.2# ./build_kernel.sh --no-check-certificate
+ Detected build host []
+ host: [x86_64]
+ git HEAD commit: [3b8714a41677a022608ba1f4838c94c8c172e496]
Installing: gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf
-----------------------------
--2013-11-14 09:06:35--  https://launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries/trunk/2013.04/+download/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.04-20130415_linux.tar.xz
Resolving launchpad.net... 91.189.89.223, 91.189.89.222
Connecting to launchpad.net|91.189.89.223|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I'm by no means a Linux pro, but I'm learning. Am I using the `--no-check-certificate` flag correctly?

Comment: Have you tried with --no-check-certificate like it tells you to?

Comment: @pjc50 - thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I have tried that, and got the same result. Added the info to the question

Comment: Any why the downvote? How can I make the question better?

Comment: Not my downvote .. I think realistically you're going to have to work out what this SSL connection is and why it doesn't work (firewall?). A build system with network dependencies seems mad to me, but I've not used it.

Comment: @pcj50 - I shouldn't be behind any firewalls, but I'll check again. I've begun researching the SSL connection error message. Thanks again!

Comment: You may want to check for updates to the scripts / repositories you are using, perhaps something has moved and is no longer being served from the original location.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the pre-built image that Andrew provides? http://icculus.org/~hendersa/android/

Just use the download it here link in the Android::Overview() section.

Comment: Thanks! I think I might just do this for now. I'd like to learn how to build from source though.

Comment: @Thomas No problem. Andrew was in one of my graduate courses this past summer and is really helpful when it comes to building linux kernels. Shoot him an email. I'm sure he'll try to help you out if he has time.